# how to write this equation In mathematica. where is W is random value either 0 or 1

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

how to write this equation In mathematica. where is W is random value either 0 or 1. i want to run to certain N=100

I already have

```
w[j, 0, 1] = IntegerPart[ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2, 2}]], 
D[x[0, t], t] = Sum[w[[j, 0, l]]*x[j, t]*x[l, t], {0, 100}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? And what do you intend to do with it? If you're not able to write an equation yourself there's presumably not much that you can do afterwards.

Comment: w[j, 0, 1] = IntegerPart[ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2, 2}]], D[x[0, t], t] = Sum[w[[j, 0, l]]*x[j, t]*x[l, t], {0, 100}]      that's what i got

Comment: I'm awfully sorry to say, but you've got basically everything wrong. I suggest you read up on some introductory text on Mathematica (like [this one](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/) or [this](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/)) and at least look up the help pages of all functions you use to see if you have the syntax right, because what you're currently doing isn't going to take you very far.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 3;
w = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {n, n, n}];
xx = Array[x, n];
eqs = Table[x[i]'[t] == Sum[w[[j, i, l]] x[j]@t x[l]@t, {j, n}, {l, n}] - 
                        Sum[w[[i, j, l]] x[i]@t x[l]@t, {j, n}, {l, n}], {i, n}]
nd = First@ NDSolve[Join[eqs, Thread[Through[xx[0]] == RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]]], 
                    xx, {t, 0, 1}]

Plot[Through[xx[t]] /. nd, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]